# Exception serializing Anonymous Type to JSON when nested property names are the same in .net5+

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I'm migrating some test projects from .netcore 3.1 to .net6 and hit an unexpected exception while serializing an anonymous type to json.

```cs
var obj = new 
{
  input = new {
    foo = "foo"
  },
  INPUT = new {
    foo = "foo"
  }
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj); // throws an exception
```

Previously in .netcore 3.1 this was acceptable and would return:

```json
{"input":{"foo":"foo"},"INPUT":{"foo":"bar"}}
```

But in .net6 an exception is thrown:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: 
Members 'input' and 'INPUT' on type 
'<>f__AnonymousType0`2[<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.String],<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.String]]' 
cannot both bind with parameter 'input' in the deserialization constructor.
```

I've tried various JsonSerializerOptions thinking that case sensitivity or insensitivity was the issue with no luck.

However if I created my Anonymous Type as classes, JsonSerialization has no problems:

```cs
public class Obj
{
    public Input input { get; set; }
    public Input INPUT { get; set; }
}
    
public class Input
{
    public string foo { get; set; } 
}
```

```cs
var obj = new Obj(){ input = new Input() { foo = "bar" }, INPUT = new Input() { foo = "bar" }};
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
```

returns:

```json
{"input":{"foo":"bar"},"INPUT":{"foo":"bar"}}
```

So what is it about serializing anonymous types that is causing this exception?

Comment: Did it work in .NET 5, or did you jump from 3.1 to 6? I am guessing it would fail in .NET 5 but I'd like to confirm whether you ever tried it there.

Comment: var obj = new  { input = new Input() { foo = "bar" }, INPUT = new Input() { foo = "bar" }};  doesnt work too

Comment: but var obj = new { input = new  { foo = "foo" }, INPUT = new Input() { foo = "foo" } }; works

Comment: but Newtonsoft.Json works in ANY CASE . Glory to James Newton-King! Job well done!

Comment: @dbc, works in 3.1, fails in .net5+

Comment: @Serge, confirmed it works with newtonsoft.json.  But... I'm looking for a solution with System.Text.Json

Comment: @DaveBaghdanov You can't create anything good using  the bad  (and the wrong)  tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The breaking change (arguably a regression) was introduced in [.NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-next-for-system-text-json/#whats-new-in-net-5-0):

> Support deserializing objects using parameterized constructors

It looks to be symptomatic only for types with parameterized constructors with multiple arguments whose names differ only in **case**, specifically `input` and `INPUT` in your example.  As documented in [How to use immutable types and non-public accessors with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability?pivots=dotnet-5-0),

> The parameter names of a parameterized constructor must match the property names and types. **Matching is case-insensitive**, and the constructor parameter must match the actual property name even if you use [JsonPropertyName] to rename a property.

It appears that it is the case-insensitive constructor parameter matching that is tripping the serializer up.  An anonymous type has exactly one  constructor -- an auto-generated parameterized constructor whose argument names match the property names exactly.  And because the case-insensitive parameter-to-constructor-argument binding algorithm does not distinguish between `input` and `INPUT` in the argument list, an exception gets thrown during contract generation that multiple properties *cannot both bind with parameter 'input'*.

Now, arguably, the exception should not be thrown during **contract generation**, but during **deserialization**.  After all, if `System.Text.Json` cannot determine a unique constructor to use during deserialization, it still will allow you to **serialize** the type (demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cXykp8)).  You may want to [report an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Aarea-System.Text.Json) to Microsoft regarding the regression.

As a workaround, you will need to serialize using types for which this is not a problem, e.g.:

1. Use mutable types with parameterless constructors (which you are doing with your `Obj` class).
2. Use records with distinct property names whose JSON property names are overridden via [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute), e.g.:

   ```
   public record Foo(string foo);

   public record Input([property:JsonPropertyName("input")] Foo lowerInput, [property:JsonPropertyName("INPUT")] Foo upperInput);

   var obj = new Input(new("foo"), new("foo"));

   var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj); // Works fine.
   ```

   Demo #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qI1zqC).

   Or if you prefer a more generic solution, you can use a record for the object with the case-invariant duplicate names and anonymous types for everything else like so:

   ```
   public static class InputExtensions
   {
       public record Input<TInput>([property:JsonPropertyName("input")] TInput lowerInput, [property:JsonPropertyName("INPUT")] TInput upperInput);
       public static Input<TInput> ToInput<TInput>(this (TInput, TInput) pair) => new Input<TInput>(pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
   }

   var obj = (new { foo = "foo" }, new { foo = "foo" }).ToInput();

   var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj); // works fine.
   ```

   Demo #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j6XgjY).
3. Use a dictionary:

   ```
   var obj = new [] { ("input", new { foo = "foo" } ), ("INPUT", new { foo = "foo" } ) }
       .ToDictionary(i => i.Item1, i => i.Item2);

   var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj); // works fine.
   ```

   Demo #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L7PbPK).
4. Revert back to Json.NET temporarily until the regression is fixed by Microsoft, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75317065/exception-serializing-anonymous-type-to-json-when-nested-property-names-are-the?noredirect=1#comment132900680_75317065) by [Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11392290/serge).

Comment: I'd definitely report this as a bug. Binding to constructor parameters should follow the same rules as binding to properties.

Comment: Thanks, this is some great insight.  I'll gather my notes and open an issue